# ”check” function – OK to throw in destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

My goal is to provide a function with the following functionality:

```
// Will throw iff a != 42.
check(a == 42) << a << " is not equal to 42!";
```

I have the following:

```
class check
{
public:
    check(bool everything_OK = false)
        : should_throw{!everything_OK}
    { }

    check(const check&) = delete;

    ~check() noexcept(false)
    {
        if (should_throw && !uncaught_exception()) {
            throw runtime_error(stream.str());
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    check& operator << (T&& t)
    {
        if (!should_throw) {
            return *this;
        }

        stream << std::forward<T>(t);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    const bool should_throw;
    stringstream stream;
};
```

The thing is, all guidelines I have read forbid throwing in the destructor. I have also read experts saying they do not know of a good use of std:uncaught_exception. Can I still achieve what I want?

ADDITION:
Loki’s point below can be fixed by defining a macro:

```
#define my_check(expr) (expr) ? ((void)0) : check(false)
```

But once we allow ourselves to use macros, there are other solutions provided below.

Comment: Added noexcept(false)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the throwing out of the destructor (which is a bad idea).

My main problem is with usage:

```
check(a == 42) << a << " is not equal to 42!";
```

Here you present a trivial case. But not all error checking is trivial. I think a more realistic case (that will happen more often than you think);

```
Universe  a;
// .... STUFF
check(a.theMeaningLTUAE(42)) << a << " The truth not reached " << a.checkInvariants();
```

Here we have calls to functions that will need to be evaluated even if they are never used (specifically `checkInvariants()` may be expensive (or even the streaming of `a`)). If the check passes you are still obliged to call it here but its value are simply discarded. I would prefer that the function is never called if no error message is going to be produced.

What you really want is a short cut operator that prevents subsequent operations from happening. Note overloading `&&` and `||` on a class does not yield short-cut operators.

Or alternatively any functions should be passed as callbacks to `operator<<` and only evaluated if there output is required.

Comment: Very good point about how the work preparing an argument for `operator<<` is not elided by the early return therein.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: The language guarantees that all parameters are fully evaluated before a function is called. `operator<<` is simply a function call, thus all parameters must be fully evaluated before the call is made. Thus you can not elide the call to any functions. The reason for this is that functions can have side affects, the compiler can not make assumptions that it is not required.

Comment: That's what I tried to agree with, but used too few words to do so with clarity. To take your example, the call to `a.checkInvariants()` is not elided by the early return in `check::operator<<`. Usage like `altcheck(a.theMeaningLTUAE(42), [&](ostream& o) { o << a << " The truth not reached " << a.checkInvariants(); })` should address this. The implementation would be much lighter, but the lambda syntax is heavy here.

Comment: You raise a good point, thanks. My main reason for opening this question, however, is the “throwing from the destructor” issue.

Comment: To expand a bit: basically your objection can be fixed by defining a macro making use of the ?: operator. Then no << operator will even be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to sidestep the use of `std::uncaught_exception`, as well as address the very good point Loki Astari made about the throwaway work done preparing for calls to `check::operator<<` is to use an alternate approach. The calling code would look like this:

```
// Will throw iff a != 42.
check(a == 42, [&](ostream& err) { err << a << " is not equal to 42!"; });
```

That lambda feels a bit heavy for something you want to be easy to use. With macros it could even look like this (but is the cure worse than the disease?):

```
CHECK(a == 42, err << a << " is not equal to 42!");
```

To implement this, `check` becomes a simple function, so all concerns about throwing in a destructor vanish:

```
template <typename Describe>
void check(bool success, Describe describe_failure)
{
    if (!success)
    {
        stringstream message;
        describe_failure(message);
        throw runtime_error(message.str());
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that there are alternative solutions if macros are allowed. Perhaps the magic word “err” should be omitted as well?

Comment: @Ben I was torn on that as well, but making it either `CHECK(a == 42, a << " is not equal to 42!")` or `CHECK(a == 42, << a << " is not equal to 42!")` seemed even worse.

Answer (score 1):

For what you appear to be trying to accomplish, the risk of a call to `std::terminate` doesn't seem like as horrible a problem as the usual case, for three reasons:

- Someone is unlikely to hold on to an instance of `CheckStream`, so there's a smaller window
- In its nameless-temporary usage, the stream of `operator<<` calls are also relatively unlikely to throw, and
- I'm guessing this used in unit tests rather than main code lines, so a `std::terminate` isn't as likely to be catastrophic (though still annoying if it blocks subsequent tests).

That said, it's still a risk, and this use of `std::uncaught_exception` is a [bad idea](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm).

Ignoring the use of `std::uncaught_exception` (i.e. pretending it always fails) there are two operations to worry about: the `operator<<` call and the preparation of its arguments; an exception in either would crash and burn. It may be helpful cut down on the potential for the former by adding a try/catch around `stream << std::forward<T>(t);`, but that doesn't help the latter case of preparing `t`.

One way to resolve this would be to move the exception from the destructor. Perhaps standardize on always requiring checks to end with `<< std::endl`. Then `CheckStream` could decide whether to throw inside `operator<<` instead of its destructor. But how do you enforce the trailing `endl`? All I can think of is throwing an exception in the destructor if you didn't see it. That's back to square one, but at least the omission is a calling programmer's misuse, so could be fair grounds for `std::terminate`.

Comment: What do you mean is the problem if operator << throws? 

That would give a normal std::bad_alloc (or similar) exception, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sure, std::bad_alloc is likely, but as operator<< can be provided by other people, it can do arbitrary amounts of work. So the window of worry from (`check(cond)`, through `<< a` and `<< b`, to its destruction) is potentially wider than it looks.

Comment: But why should I worry about that? The exception will be correctly propagated, won’t it?

Comment: I'll need more time to fully wrap my head around http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm, but there the subtle problems with using `std::uncaught_exception` are covered. The simplest problem: you can't know whether the current exception will be caught closer to the destructor than the `runtime_error` would be. If all you want to know is the problem with throwing from a destructor, then codereview may be the wrong place for this question.

Comment: I have read that article and I don’t think the “subtle problems” there applies.

Comment: OK, I have now made up a (quite contrived) example where it actually matters. It is probably best to use a function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not throwing in destructor is possible if changing << to a comma is acceptable:

```
check(a == 42, a, " is not equal to 42.");
```

But this is not as readable. The definition:

```
template<typename... Args>
void check(bool everything_OK, Args&&... args)
{
    // Code which throws
}
```